# Vuetify vertical expansion panel

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to know how to use the Vuetify expansion panel in sideways opening mode instead of opening downward.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage

Comment: do you have a demo of what it should look like? does it enable horizontal scroll?